# How to use optional parameters in Yii URL Manager?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, yii

I have a problem with Yii urlManager.

I have a page that is a list of videos, so I add the following rule:

```
'videos'=>'video/index'
```

Now I want to add the page:

```
'videos_pag<Video_page:\d+>'=>'video/index'
```

---

### Is there a way in order to put the two rules together?

I tried this:

```
'videos(_pag<Video_page:\d+>)?'=>'video/index',
```

but it does not work properly.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Use two lines, if first fails, second will work (if everything correct) :)

```
'videos_pag<Video_page:\d+>'=>'video/index',
'videos'=>'video/index',
```

Comment: @khizaransari by milliseconds maybe.